# Windows 7 - BSOD PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, bsod

So.. I tried last known good config, tried booting into Safe mode, tried system restore -- nothing.

I get `PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED` and error code is: `0x0000006B`.

Trying to run `sfc /scannow` in Syste Recovery Options' command prompt. But I get `There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete. Restart Windows and run sfc again."

I have and still same problem. I did however do System Restore to like Feb 18 and it worked but now its back again...

Help? My computer is 64-bit and custom built. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can occur if the `Bootcat.cache` file is corrupted or the size of the file is different than it was at the last successful start.

The Bootcat.cache file is located at `%SystemRoot%\system32\codeintegrity`.

Start the computer from a Windows install or repair disk, or perhaps a Linux LiveCD or alike.  Delete the Bootcat.cache file, and then restart the computer.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/process1initializationfailed-blue-screen-stop-06b/18250508-4ef2-4ddd-9599-ee1b11e32a32)